# Naming convention for "admin" UI and "public facing" UI

Tags: gui-design, terminology, conventions, administration

I have a social network kind of app that has two dramatically different interfaces:

1. The admin part, where the owner administers the account
2. The public facing part, what all users sees

I need to name the links for the administrator, going from one part to the other. Currently I'm using "Admin" and "Site", and it's causing unnecessary confusion (chiefly the latter).

Please, are there any self explanatory conventions regarding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a UX perspective, you want to make this as **simple to recall** as possible. It's also helpful to think of the URL popping up in the suggestions when a user starts typing: it should be **simple to distinguish** between the two views.

Off the top of my head:

- #### `app.com/admin`
- #### `admin.app.com`

So the public-facing "regular" site would just get **`app.com`**.

Comment: Thank you, those are really good points. But my biggest pain right now is naming the public facing part - a generic name for the administrator when leaving the administration part of the site to the area where all the users are.

Comment: `app.com` ... What am I missing?

Comment: Yes that's a good suggestion, naming the public facing part the name of the app.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same. I get the point "not use name" for public, but for internal usage what name do you use? Admin of admin is ok, but "Public" for Public data structures?

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Admin** and **Profile**?

Profile since its a social network.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it's more like Facebook where you land on a feed of everything, rather than your profile. Furthermore, the link only needs to be descriptive to the administrator, not all the users.

Comment: /admin and /view then perhaps?